# Как можно определить корректность подсказок в запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

Например, был запрос, который долго выполнялся, так как сканировали индексы, вместо поиска в них.

Я в него добавил подсказку "принудительный поиск по индексу" и получил ощутимый выигрыш во времени выполнения.

Microsoft в MSDN пишет, что оптимизатор почти всегда прав и нужно прибегать к подсказкам в последнюю очередь.

Так же, без подсказок в разное время для одного и того же запроса, могут генерироваться разные планы в зависимости от загрузки сервера, состояния БД и т д...

Можно ли считать подсказки, которые привели к понижению времени выполнения однозначно правильными или может быть существует какой-то другой критерий?

Comment: Время выполнения запроса не является точным критерием т.к. запрос с одним и тем же планом может выполниться гораздо быстрее/медленнее, в зависимости от того лежат ли данные уже в кеше, как загружен сервер и т.д., а план запроса достаточно точно покажет что надо сделать серверу, чтобы удовлетворить запрос.

Comment: Нужно смотреть план и статистику ввода-вывода. И проверять хинты после каждого обновления sql server.

Answer (score 2):

Считать подсказки, которые привели к ускорению времени выполнения, однозначно правильными нельзя. Просто потому что ускорение времени выполнения произошло только на конкретном наборе данных и с конкретной статистикой, на которую опирался сам SQL Server.

Проблема с неверно расчитанным планом чаще всего связана с устаревшей статистикой - когда SQL Server строит неоптимальный план, опираясь на неверные (устаревшие) данные. Первейшее лечение в таком случае - перестроение статистики и проверка - будет ли новый план (а он перестроится, увидев новую статистику) более оптимальным, чем ранее.

Если, несмотря на перестроение статистики, SQL Server продолжает выбирать неверный план выполнения - рекомендуется изменить запрос, упростить его, задействовав, например, временные таблицы, разделить на части (понятно, что этот пункт не подходит для простейших запросов типа select без join'ов).

И только если такая оптимизация не помогает, на крайний случай, можно применять добавление прямых подсказок.

Перечень подсказок можно найти тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx